# Two programs Powershell to convert binary to text file and reciprocally

Tags: powershell

Two PowerShell programs:

1. Convert an input binary file to output text file.
2. Another program to do the same thing in the other direction and go back to the starting binary file from the text file.

Comment: Please clarify your requirements (convert from binary to text based on what encoding?, ...) by directly updating your question, and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: are you requesting custom programming? if so, this is not the correct place - and you have not made your payment amount & method clear ... [*grin*]

Comment: Hi mklement0, on your recommendation, I tested script, fixed a bug left by writer, suggested a solution,  requested to the writer to remove the bug and clicked for acceptance his proposed script. On the basis of the manifestation of my good will, would you accept to remove the -1, please. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a base64 job

```
$text_file = "C:\Temp\1.bin.txt"
$bin_file = "C:\Temp\1.bin"

# binary -> text
[io.file]::WriteAllText($text_file, [Convert]::ToBase64String([io.file]::ReadAllBytes($bin_file)))

# text -> binary
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes($bin_file, [System.Convert]::FromBase64String([io.file]::ReadAllText($text_file)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I has just made one test: binary file --> text --> binary But both binary files are differents!

Comment: Please, could you correct your answer by replacing ReadAllBytes by ReadAllText at the end of the last line (in the txt2bin part of the script) and I will validate your answer. Thank you.